# Create SQLite db file runtime

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, code-first

I've spent a lot of time to find how create SQLite DB file runtime using EntityFramework having only model classes and DbContext

```
public class A1
{
    public int Key {get;set;} 
    public string Name {get;set;} 
}
```

There was a task to create DB file if it was not found using EF tool + System.Data.SQLite. Found solutuion were related to sqlite.net (that was not actually approved for using or other custom hand written classes).

Finally I've found a solution using 2 Nuger packages: System.Data.SQLite и SQLite.CodeFirst.

Ny own DBContext overrides OnModelCreating functions and involved SQLite.CodeFirst feature.

```
public sealed class SampleDbContext : DbContext
{
    public SampleDbContext(SQLiteConnection sqLiteConnection)
        : base(sqLiteConnection, false)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<A1> A1{ get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        var initializer =
            new SQLite.CodeFirst.SqliteDropCreateDatabaseAlways<SampleDbContext>(modelBuilder);
        Database.SetInitializer(initializer);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

A code to create db file.

```
    public void CreateDatabaseFile(string path)
    {
        try
        {
        using (SQLiteConnection sqLiteConnection = CreateConnection(path))
        using (SampleDbContext context = new SampleDbContext(sqLiteConnection))
        {
            DropCreateDatabaseAlways<SampleDbContext> initializator =
                new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<SampleDbContext>();
            Database.SetInitializer(initializator);

            context.SaveChanges();
            // do not delete this log trace. we need some DB touch
            _log.Trace("Db Context validated. Found {0} Customer(s)", context.A1.Count());
        }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        _log.Error(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SQLiteConnection CreateConnection(string path)
    {
        SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder builder =
        (SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder) SQLiteProviderFactory.Instance.CreateConnectionStringBuilder();
        builder.DataSource = path;
        builder.FailIfMissing = false;

        return new SQLiteConnection(builder.ToString());
    }
```

And some magic in app.config (few lines added by manually). Does anybody know more beatifull solution ?

```html
  <system.data>
     <DbProviderFactories>
       <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
       <add name="SQLite Data Provider (Entity Framework 6)" invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite (Entity Framework 6)" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderFactory, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
          <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite" />
       <add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite" />
        </DbProviderFactories>
      </system.data>
      <entityFramework>
     <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
       <parameters>
      <parameter value="v12.0" />
       </parameters>
     </defaultConnectionFactory>
     <providers>
       <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
          <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
       <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
        </providers>
      </entityFramework>
```

Comment: well, you dont actually need all of this for the task. but what exactly is your question?

Comment: then describe what do I need? maybe I follow wrong way?

Comment: what do you need? tell me what do you want? as you may know, SqLite provider itself does not provide code first functionality (Create Database, Create Table), so you'll need the code first extension (if it does work)... but you didn't specify what you are trying to achieve (with this question), as your main task seems to be done

Comment: I supposed I've described. I need create SQLite db file (with db metadata) having only Model / POCO classes and EF (or EF depended components). Found solutiob looked quite complecated and were "hand"written. I needed ready box-solution